# Java-EE redirect to a custom error page

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, redirect, error-handling

Is there way to include error page for any wrong path request?
I need all wrong path requested by the user to be sent to error.jsp

For example if "/example" is part of the web.xml then it would send to localhost:8080/example
If user specifies localhost:8080/examp then it would redirect to error.jsp

I tried the following code in the web.xml and created a error.jsp inside Web Pages directory in Netbeans and it still sent me to yahoo error handle page:

```
<web-app>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

error.jsp

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Show Error Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
        <h1>Opps...</h1>
        <p>An error occurred.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: show us the `error.jsp` page , your configuration looks fine

Comment: That error page configuration will only work if it is your server that actually gets the request. Apparently, that is not the case here.

Comment: Should I handle wrong path with the custom error page or just let it go to the generic yahoo error handling? Would web.xml have some kind of filtering so to redirect all the wrong page requests?

Answer (score 2):

First create a custom servlet and use it for both exceptions and errors. Refer the below code.

```
@WebServlet("/AppExceptionHandler")
public class AppExceptionHandler extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processError(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processError(request, response);
    }

    private void processError(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        // Analyze the servlet exception
        Throwable throwable = (Throwable) request
                .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
        Integer statusCode = (Integer) request
                .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
        String servletName = (String) request
                .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.servlet_name");
        if (servletName == null) {
            servletName = "Unknown";
        }
        String requestUri = (String) request
                .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri");
        if (requestUri == null) {
            requestUri = "Unknown";
        }

        // Set response content type
          response.setContentType("text/html");

          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
          out.write("<html><head><title>Exception/Error Details</title></head><body>");
          if(statusCode != 500){
              out.write("<h3>Error Details</h3>");
              out.write("<strong>Status Code</strong>:"+statusCode+"<br>");
              out.write("<strong>Requested URI</strong>:"+requestUri);
          }else{
              out.write("<h3>Exception Details</h3>");
              out.write("<ul><li>Servlet Name:"+servletName+"</li>");
              out.write("<li>Exception Name:"+throwable.getClass().getName()+"</li>");
              out.write("<li>Requested URI:"+requestUri+"</li>");
              out.write("<li>Exception Message:"+throwable.getMessage()+"</li>");
              out.write("</ul>");
          }

          out.write("<br><br>");
          out.write("<a href=\"index.html\">Home Page</a>");
          out.write("</body></html>");
    }
}
```

Then configure it in deployment descriptor which is your web.xml

```
        <welcome-file-list>
               <welcome-file> index.html</welcome-file >
        </welcome-file-list>
        <error-page>
               <error-code> 404</error-code>
               <location> /AppExceptionHandler</location >
        </error-page>

        <error-page>
               <exception-type> javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
               <location>/AppExceptionHandler</location >
        </error-page>
        <error-page>
  <exception-type >java.lang.Throwable </exception-type>
  <location >/AppExceptionHandler </location>
```

when a exception occures it will call the AppExceptionHandler class and then it will cause to display a custom error page.